# Is the usr directory local to users?

Tags: filesystem

I understand each users' home is under /home/, however I'm confused if usr is local to the user? If so, does that mean its file change whenever a new user logs in? or is it a global, shared directory?

Comment: Answer your own question: Use `ls -l` to discover who owns /usr and it's subsidiary directories.

Comment: Alternately, see https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html

Comment: Great idea! Don't even know why I didn't think of that. Root owns it.

Comment: Unix System Resources :)